# How disable IPv6 on Fedora Silverblue?

Tags: fedora, systemd, systemd-networkd

I tried to create a file **/etc/sysctl.d/10-network-override.conf** then **sudo systemctl daemon-reload**

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.wls1.disable_ipv6=1
```

Also, tried creating **/etc/systemd/network/20-IpV6-disable.network** then **systemctl restart systemd-networkd**

```
[Match]
Name=wls1
[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv4
IPv6AcceptRA=no
```

Both solutions work temporarily and after rebooting I get IPv6 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use just these two settings which are enough:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

You will continue to see IPv6 addresses assigned to your interfaces but that's OK because they are [Link Local addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) and can only be used within your LAN. These addresses are not routable.

If you want to go even further, you can simply disable the ipv6 kernel module, create a file e.g. `/etc/modprobe.d/disable-ipv6.conf` with this:

```
blacklist ipv6
```

and reboot.